# DateTime.ParseExact() throws exception when trying to parse twitter api created_at

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-web-api, twitter

I'm using Web API to query Twitter's REST api and I'm trying to parse the `created_at` value to a `DateTime` using `DateTime.ParseExact(...)`:

```
CreatedAt = DateTime.ParseExact(tweet["created_at"],
                                  "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss K yyyy",
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                  DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal)
```

I get the following exception:

The best overloaded method match for 'System.DateTime.ParseExact(string, string, System.IFormatProvider, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles)' has some invalid arguments.

An example value of `tweet["created_at"]` is : Wed Feb 15 19:06:56 +0000 2017

Comment: Ran into the same & turned out I didn't need to bother parsing dates, int, or decimal - it worked w/o that. Solution below turns it into a string and then back out again, so maybe it was already a recognizable DateTime to start with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try

```
CreatedAt = DateTime.ParseExact(tweet["created_at"].ToString(),
                              "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss K yyyy",
                              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                              DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal)
```

The problem isn't that the format is wrong, it's that the arguments going into ParseExact are wrong, so my guess would be that tweet[] doesn't return a string type.

Comment: Thanks, that's all it was.

Answer (score 1):

> `Convert.ToDateTime(doc["date"].ToString())`
>   It will work